# Iota to define keys on a Go map?

Tags: go, iota

Let's suppose we have a `map[int]string` and we want to define it like this:

```
var a map[int]string =  {
 1: "some"
 3: "value"
 4: "maintained"
 7: "manually"
 // more 100 entries...
}
```

I would like to maintain the values manually because they have no pattern, but the keys have. Is there a way to maintain the key list just like we do with enum values using `1 << 1 + iota`?

I'm not asking if it's possible to use iota as a map key (unfortunately it's not AFAIK), just if there is an equally elegant way to create the keys on a defined sequence.

Comment: would be really nice to be able to use iotas everywhere in Go, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to store the ordered values as a slice, and then use an init function to generate the map like this:

```
var a map[int]string
var vals = []string{
    "some",
    "value",
    "maintained",
    "manually",
}

func init() {
    a = make(map[int]string)
    for idx, val := range vals {
        a[idxToKey(idx)] = val
    }
}

func idxToKey(i int) int {
    return 1<<1 + i
}
```

Run it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/uEqJp3e3RI).

You can change `idxToKey` to be whatever transformation you want. I've used the one you gave in this case, but it could be anything. The argument goes where you'd normally put the `iota` keyword.

Comment: Use [`make(T, n)`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels) map of type T with initial space for n elements, for example,`a = make(map[int]string, len(vals))`

Comment: That'd add a bit of performance, but maps are still amortized O(1), and this is at initialization. I felt that it would just distract from the point of the answer.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately there is nothing as elegant as iota to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be have an array/slice of all the words and loop through similar to this;

```
var words []string
var a map[int]string

for i, v := range words {
   a[1 << 1 + i] = v
}
```